# How can I tell turtles to avoid stepping on certain patches?

Tags: simulation, netlogo

I am currently simulating a fire-evacuation model, I tried to tell turtles to head into exits without stepping on black patches, but my code does not work properly.

This is the code I've been using to thjs problem : 
to Go

```
 ask people
  [face one-of patches with [pycor <= -24  and pycor >= -30  and 
  pxcor <= 26  and pxcor >= 20 ]
  fd 0.5 ]

 ask people with [ points = 1 ] [ set color pink ]
 ask people with [ points = 0 ] [ set color red ]
 ask people with [ color = red ] [ fd 0 ]
tick
end

to avoid-black

 ask people [
 if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 0.5 = grey - 3
 [ set heading ( - heading ) fd 0.5 ]]
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ave555, hi!  You've come to the right place to get help!

There are several different issues with your code.

- black is not the same as "grey - 2" so your test for black may fail, depending
  on how you set patch colors in your wall.
- the command "avoid-black" is never called in your "go" step so it has no effect
- I'm guessing you have set the screen to larger than the default which has 
  coordinates between -16 and 16,   or your test for patches around 32 will fail.
- You might have not ALSO have forgotten to ask the viewport not to wraparound.
  You have to set that or you will get very bizarre behavior. ( try it out )
- By the way, setting heading to -heading is not what you want. Heading is 
  an angle. You want to subtract 180 from it to reverse direction. Or add 180.
- Try the following code.  Step through it
  one step at a time as written and you can see it mostly works.  Black is detected
  and the person rotates 180 degrees and jumps 5 steps! So far,so good.
- But, then they just turn around and head back into the wall because nothing tells 
  them not to.

The code below is very verbose.  Run one go-step at a time and watch the output. It tells you what the avoid-black decision code is looking at.

I hope this helps!

```
;; This code is incomplete but should make it easier to see why the people are not going where you expect

breed [people person]
people-own [ points]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set pcolor white]
  ask patches with [pycor < -5] [ set pcolor black ]

  create-people 1 [ setxy random-pxcor 5 set points random 2 set color green set size 3 ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  let chosen-patch one-of patches with [pycor <= -12  and pycor >= -15  and 
    pxcor <= 15  and pxcor >= 10 ]


  ask chosen-patch [ set pcolor red]

  ask people
    [
          face chosen-patch
      fd 0.5 ]

 ask people with [ points = 1 ] [ set color pink ]
 ask people with [ points = 0 ] [ set color red ]
 ask people with [ color = red ] [ fd 0 ]

  avoid-black

  tick
end

to avoid-black
  ;; note:    grey -3   is 2.   black is zero. 
  ;;let wall-color grey - 3
  let wall-color black

 ask people [
    print " "
   type ticks type ", pcolor of patch-ahead is " type [pcolor] of patch-ahead 0.5 type ", and wall-color is " print wall-color
 if-else ([pcolor] of patch-ahead 0.5 = wall-color)
 [    print "test succeded, wall ahead, reverse and jump"
      set heading (  heading - 180 ) fd 5]
  [ print "test failed, no wall ahead. Keep going." ]
  ]
 end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I really appreciate
I asked about black just to make it easier to understand, I am working with grey-2
When I execute this code, the turtles do not move...
Can you please tell me what's wrong with this one :  
to avoid-wall

 ask people [
    if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = black
    [ set heading ( 180 ) fd 3 ]]
end 
I did the -180 you've told me